# Алгоритм Евклида для вычисления НОД

Tags: алгоритм, математика

В школьной презентации алгоритм Евклида описан так:

> Заменяем большее из двух чисел разностью большего и меньшего до тех пор, пока они не станут равны. Это и есть НОД.

А я привык к такому алгоритму:

- Большее число делим на меньшее.
- Если делится без остатка, то меньшее число и есть НОД (следует выйти из цикла).
- Если есть остаток, то большее число заменяем на остаток от деления.
- Переходим к пункту 1.

Откуда взят алгоритм, представленный выше? Обоснован ли он математически?

Comment: Для тех кто просто проходил мимо - в вопросе идет речь о наибольшем общем делителе

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Алгоритм Евклида полностью аналогичен "привычному", за исключением того, что он по древности своей считает остаток, отнимая по одному меньшему числу от большего, пока результат не станет меньше ЭТОГО меньшего, а Вы умеете сразу делить с остатком.

Answer (score 4):

Это и есть тот самый алгоритм, который и применял сам Евклид. Называется он *"Геометрический Алгоритм Евклида"*

Согласно [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.93.D0.B5.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC_.D0.95.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B4.D0.B0) он звучит следующим образом:

> Пусть даны два отрезка длины **a** и **b**. Вычтем из большего отрезка меньший
>   и заменим больший отрезок полученной разностью. Повторяем эту
>   операцию, пока отрезки не станут равны. Если это произойдёт, то
>   исходные отрезки соизмеримы, и последний полученный отрезок есть их
>   наибольшая общая мера. Если общей меры нет, то процесс бесконечен

Дополнительно можно посмотреть здесь: ["Евклида алгоритм"](http://www.russika.ru/ef.php?s=3564)

Answer (score 2):

А есть еще и такой вариант -

```
НОД(2*a, 2*b) = 2*НОД(a,b)
НОД(2*a, b) = НОД(a,b) при нечетном b
```

ну, а при нечетных - как обычно... :)